# php template and html tidyness

Tags: php, templates

Would this technically pass as a basic level template system in php?

So there are two files, index.php and Template_Module.php

Here is index.php code

```
<?php

include("Template_Module.php");

$set_name = "My Website";
$set_desc = "My Website for random bla bla";
$set_key  = "site, random, bla, for";

echo template_header_object($set_name, $set_desc, $set_key);
```

and here is Template_Module.php code

```
<?php

function template_header_object($set_title, $set_desc, $set_keywords) {

     $title_object = htmlspecialchars($set_title);    //lets get html title to pass
     $desc_object  = htmlspecialchars($set_desc);     //lets get meta description to pass
     $keyw_object  = htmlspecialchars($set_keywords); //lets get meta keywords to pass

     $template_create_object .= <<<OBJECT
<!doctype html>
     <html>
         <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
                 <title>$title_object</title>
    <!-- general meta -->
             <meta name="description" content="$desc_object">
             <meta name="keywords" content="$keyw_object">

    <!-- mobile specific meta -->
             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">           

    <!-- open graph meta -->
             <meta property="og:title" content="$title_object">
             <meta property="og:image" content="/assets/img/logo_fbtype.png">
             <meta property="og:site_name" content="$title_object">
             <meta property="og:description" content="$desc_object">

    <!-- style sheets and scripts -->
             <link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
             <link href="/assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
             <link href="/assets/img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">

                <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
                <![endif]-->

             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
         </head>
     <body></body></html>        
OBJECT;

     return $template_create_object;

}
```

And is there a way I can improve the way html is rendered to browser, so the source code looks nicer instead of being completely off from how it looks at `$template_create_object .= <<<OBJECT` and is there a better way for passing values from index.php to template_object.php

Comment: you could use smarty which is a popular open source php templating system

Comment: or use [mustache.php](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php)

Comment: As per the other comments, really. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @BenM I my self am a self learner what I learned about PHP is what I know and frankly there is still more to go. Life would be easier if I knew or understood php oop but sadly I tried and can't seem to understand it. So I am stuck with functions and what not. Also I don't think smarty is included in my host as there are bunch of other things disabled like fileinfo and others. So this is why I am trying to create a basic way for making pages, there aren't going to be much prob 4 same and rest dynamic.

Comment: You could make your template a class that you instantiate. That would prevent you from having to echo all the html which is not usually the best idea. You would simply put the html in a function called something like `function create_template() {` and then close the php tag `?>`. After the function you would then reopen the tag `<?php` and continue parsing the rest of your php. That way hte server doesn't take a performance hit when parsing the large echo. Just a thought...

Comment: @War10ck you mean by using closing php function ?> then putting html and then ones more continuing the code?

Comment: @Cl' you got it. That's what I was getting at. My apologies to for referencing classes and oop. I didn't see your comment on that before I posted mine. [Here](http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Web-Development-Edition/dp/0672329166/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1357307280&sr=8-1&keywords=php+and+mysql) is a good resource you may be interested in. Starting on page 159, it talks about oop. Its my personal preference.

Comment: This is a codereview request. http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @War10ck I actually own a copy of that book :) bough it of Amazon a while-back. But as I said I can't understand OOP. I can make a fairly simple class controller and functions in that controller but I output the content in similar way as provided in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, it's a perfectly good way of doing a basic template in PHP. It's very basic, and doesn't offer much flexibility, but it's a quick and easy starting point. If you don't need anything more complex, it'll suit you fine. (If you do need something more complex, there are plenty of open source PHP templating packages you can use)
2. Seriously, don't worry about how the finished HTML code looks. You shouldn't need to look at it anyway (If you need to debug it, use the browser's DOM view; it's a much easier way to work with it than viewing the source, even if the source if neat and tidy).